# To print arrays value using "/" in bar chart

Tags: javascript, c#

I had to print the values of `Active_Employees` & `Employees_Plan` in bar chart like in this 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9f2i.png)
Means to make a bar representing the comparison in the last bar. It would be more suitable if concise code is provided.

```
function BarChart()
{
    var emp = 0;
    myData = "{ 'date':'" + startdate + "', 'Level1':'0','Level2':'0','Level3':'0','Level4':'0','Level5':'0','Level6':'0', 'EmployeeId':'" + emp + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NewDashboard.asmx/BarChart",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:myData,
        success: OnSuccessBarChart,
        //    function (result) {
        //    alert(result.d);
        //},
        error: onError,
        cache: false
    });
}
function OnSuccessBarChart(data,status)
{
    var bar_array  = [];

    if (data.d != null) {

        var bar_data = jsonParse(data.d);

        $.each(bar_data, function (i, option) {

            //OSA.push(
            //    {
            //        name: option[i].Active_Employees,
            //        data: parseFloat(option[i].Employees_Plan)
            //    })
            bar_array.push(
                parseFloat([option.Employees_Plan]),
                 parseFloat([option.Active_Employees]),
                  parseFloat([option.Employees_Plan] + "/" + [option.Active_Employees])
                );
        });
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'BarCharts',
            type: 'bar',
            height: 300
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Month Planned by Employees '
        },
        colors: [
                '#604228'
        ],
        credits: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
            style: {
                color: '#F0F0F0'
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return this.x + ':' + this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,

                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Plan of Current Month', 'Total Active Employee', 'Plans Made by Active Employees'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Plans of Active Employees',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
    }
        },

        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            data: bar_array

        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: "It would be more suitable if concise code is provided" I liked this... :-). Anyways could you please let us know what is the error?

Comment: What is your question? We won´t write the code for you. Provide the code that shows what you´re trying to achieve and where you´re stuck, not your entire app. Btw.: I doubt this question is related to C# at all.

Comment: var bar_array  = [];

    if (data.d != null) {

        var bar_data = jsonParse(data.d);

        $.each(bar_data, function (i, option) {
            bar_array.push(
                parseFloat([option.Employees_Plan]),
                 parseFloat([option.Active_Employees]),
                  parseFloat([option.Employees_Plan] + "/" + [option.Active_Employees]) //this line is generating issue
                );
        });

Comment: its basically of javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
      $.each(bar_data, function (i, option) {
        var emp_plan = option.Employees_Plan;
        var active_emp = option.Active_Employees;
        var plan_ratio =   emp_plan / active_emp;

        bar_array.push(
            parseFloat([option.Employees_Plan]),
             parseFloat([option.Active_Employees]),
              parseFloat(plan_ratio).toFixed(2)
            );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but i had found a way to print it ;)